# Find rows where child collection contains all elements of the list

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Given simple blog engine that has posts and tags associated with posts. 
There are 2 tables in the database: `Post` and `Tag`, also `PostTag` table for many-to-many relationship.

I have list of tags and I want to find all posts that have all of these tags (so `.IsIn()` not working here)

Question: how can I achieve it using nhibernate? (ideally with `.QueryOver<>()` method)

The problem here is that I don't even know where to start and how to implement it in pure SQL. I have 2 ideas:

1. Get all posts and then filter them with LINQ (ie with `.IsSupersetOf()` function)
2. In SQL use `WHERE EXISTS` for each item in the list

But I believe there is more elegant way

**Tables structure**

```
    CREATE TABLE Post (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
        Title NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE Tag (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
        Tag NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE PostTag (
        PostId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Post(Id),
        TagId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Tag(Id)
    );

    INSERT INTO Post(Id, Title) VALUES (1, 'Post A');
    INSERT INTO Post(Id, Title) VALUES (2, 'Post B');
    INSERT INTO Post(Id, Title) VALUES (3, 'Post C');

    INSERT INTO Tag(Id, Tag) VALUES (1, 'tagA');
    INSERT INTO Tag(Id, Tag) VALUES (2, 'tagB');

    INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (1, 1);
    INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (2, 2);
    INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (3, 1);
    INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (3, 2);
```

And I want to get post with id 3 by given list of tag id: (1, 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Queryover the solution should look like,

```
Tag tagAlias = new Tag();
Post postAlias = new Post();

Tag tagAliasInner = new Tag();
Post postAliasInner = new Post();

var subQuery = QueryOver.Of(() => postAliasInner)
    .JoinAlias(() => postAliasInner.Tags, () => tagAliasInner)
    .Where(Restrictions.EqProperty(Projections.Property(() => postAliasInner.Id),
        Projections.Property(() => postAlias.Id)))
    .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tagAliasInner.Id), ids.ToArray()))
    .Select(Projections.Count(Projections.Property(() => tagAliasInner.Id)));

var query = session.QueryOver(() => postAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => postAlias.Tags, () => tagAlias)
    .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tagAlias.Id), ids.ToArray()))
    .WithSubquery.WhereValue(ids.Count).Eq<Post>(subQuery);

var results = query.List();
```

This results in SQL,

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id3_1_,
 this_.Title as Title3_1_,
 tags3_.Post_id as Post1_,
 tagalias1_.Id as Tag2_,
 tagalias1_.Id as Id5_0_,
 tagalias1_.Text as Text5_0_ 
FROM "Post" this_
 inner join PostTag tags3_ on this_.Id=tags3_.Post_id 
 inner join "Tag" tagalias1_ on tags3_.Tag_id=tagalias1_.Id 
WHERE tagalias1_.Id in (?, ?) 
 and ? = (SELECT count(tagaliasin1_.Id) as y0_ 
            FROM "Post" this_0_
            inner join PostTag tags3_ on this_0_.Id=tags3_.Post_id 
            inner join "Tag" tagaliasin1_ on tags3_.Tag_id=tagaliasin1_.Id 
            WHERE this_0_.Id = this_.Id and tagaliasin1_.Id in (?, ?))
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ solution (nhibernate *should* be able to translate it)

```
var tags = new[] { 1 , 2 };

var postIds = PostTags
    .Where(pt => tags.Contains(pt.TagId))
    .GroupBy(pt => pt.PostId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == tags.Length)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

SQL Solution:

```
SELECT PostId
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, PostId
    FROM [PostTag]
    WHERE TagId IN (1, 2) --List of tags
    GROUP BY PostId
    ) as t1
WHERE [t1].[count] = 2 --Length of list
```

Explanation: We filter `PostTag` to only include the tags we care about. Then we group by post. If the count of the grouping equals the length of the tag list, then the post contains all tags.

Comment: @TomB. It definitely works, but after a certain limit (I believe ~10,000) it's usually better to insert into a temp table. But yes, SQL generation works for both EF and linq2sql. The SQL solution is a tidied up version of what linq2sql generates from the LINQ. I would imagine nhibernate also supports it, or at least, a version of it. It's pretty integral to querying data.